# Turning off notifications with AddEditor, AddViewer

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a script that copies the Viewers & Editors from one file on to another file, like this:

```
var arrEditors = oldFile.getEditors();  // Keep all original editors
if (arrEditors.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrEditors.length; i++) {
    newFile.addEditor(arrEditors[i]);
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that all those Editors & Viewers get an email notification each time this happens. In order to turn those notifications off, I changed up this line:

```
    newFile.addEditor(arrEditors[i]);
```

with:

```
    Drive.Permissions.insert(
      {
        'role': 'writer',
        'type': 'user',
        'value': arrEditors[i]
      },
      newFile.getId(),
      {
        'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
      });*/
```

which doesn't work*. I think I've enabled the drive api both in script/resources and in the control panel. I may be making an obvious mistake, I don't look at this stuff that often. Thanks for any help!

- Edit: it throws an "invalid permission value" error

Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are adding the User object to the permission resource not the email. Use the getEmail method on the User object to build your permission resource.

```
Drive.Permissions.insert(
      {
        'role': 'writer',
        'type': 'user',
        'value': arrEditors[i].getEmail()
      },
      newFile.getId(),
      {
        'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
      });
```